# How to auto-crop out backgrounds of logo images (ideally of any color)

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, crop

I am trying to auto-crop the background around logos. Right now I am cropping using getbbox but it does not always work.

Here are the images that I am using to test the autocropper:
[image]

After running

```
# crop out background
queries = [logo.crop(ImageOps.invert(logo).getbbox()) for logo in queries]
queries = [logo.crop(logo.getbbox()) for logo in queries]
```

This is the result:

[image]

As you can see it mostly works except for a few cases such as the logos in Adobe, Google, and LinkedIn in which the bounding box isn't what one would expect it to be. Can someone give me some insight as to why this doesn't always perform as expected and how I can improve it?

EDIT:
I tried using thresholding as suggested in the comments. It helped for the google and linkedin images but had the same effect on the adobe logo.

```
logos_gray = [logo.convert('L') for logo in logos]
threshold = 250
logos_gray = [logo.point(lambda p: p > threshold and 255) for logo in logos_gray]
logos_gray_inv = [ImageOps.invert(logo) for logo in logos_gray]
for i in range(len(logos_gray_inv)):
    logos[i] = logos[i].crop(logos_gray_inv[i].getbbox())
```

Comment: From the [documentation on `PIL.Image.getbbox`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getbbox): _Calculates the bounding box of the non-zero regions in the image._ Most likely, some backgrounds are not fully white, but may have some pixels with intensity `254` or so, such that after inverting you have non-zero pixels there. Threshold the logos with some cutoff at `252` or so, and you should be fine.

Comment: @HansHirse How do I do this exactly for RGB images? I would need some sort of composite threshold or something, no? Or should I first grayscale the image

Comment: Yes, grayscale your images beforehand.

Comment: @HansHirse I put in the edit my attempt of the implementation of the thresholding. (I admit that I am not entirely sure about the Image.point function). Anyways it seems to have helped except for the adobe logo. Is it possible that there are some stray dark pixels on the lower left border?

Comment: Most likely, yes. Maybe compression artifacts (if you're using JPEG for example). Just inspect the logo using some image editing software.

Comment: yeah that's it.. I guess it would be difficult to overcome such cases